# How to assign multiple string resources to a single textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-resources

I have created 3 strings in string resources. Every string has an external link in it. Basically I am trying to put one sentence in a `TextView` which has 3 outside links in it. Please tell how to do this in Android.

If we can assign multiple string through XML only that will be best.

Comment: 3 links in the same textview, is that what you are asking?

Comment: you cannot do that in xml however you can achieve this programmatically in your java file using concatenation.

Comment: Yeah, or manually concatenate them (put all 3 strings in the same string resource)

Comment: To Dustblue: yes.3 links in single sentence in same textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Spannable, here is example below, have a look

```
ClickableSpan linkClick = new ClickableSpan() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Link Click",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    view.invalidate();
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    if (textView.isPressed()) {
        ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        ds.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
    textView.invalidate();
  }
};
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Spannable spannableString = new SpannableString("Link in TextView");
spannableString.setSpan(linkClick, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

In this, String `Link in TextView` only "LINK" is clickable

Comment: Used spannable and it worked. Thanks. but now scrolling is not performing on textview. It is working earlier but now it has stopped working. I have used scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine your 3 links and make them clickable you can try this :

```xml
<string name="combined_links"><![CDATA[<a href="%1$s"> my link one</a> <a href="%2$s"> my link two</a> <a href="31$s"> my link three</a>]]></string>
```

```
String sentence = getString(R.string.combined_links, getString(R.string.link_one), getString(R.string.link_two), getString(R.string.link_three))
```

Comment: This is bad approach, use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: i have used this but val is coming in red. is there anything i have to import. i have also used string to store instead of var and used settext on textview but app stopped immediately.

Comment: @Rhishikesh chogale : Sorry, it's because i'm using the Kotlin Language. Just replace `val` with `String`

Comment: thanks Zach. i have used this approach. text of link is coming but links are not clickable on page

Comment: you didn't specify in your question that you wanted to make your links clickable. If you want to do it, I advise you to use a 4th String resource that includes your 3 links. I edited my post.